# How to have some ggplot elements clip and some not

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have an R Shiny app which includes a plot where you can click to leave a marker labeled with the point's x and y coordinates. This code reproduces the relevant parts with some artificial data:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput('plot', click = 'plot_click')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, ll = -1:-10, ul = 2:11), aes(x, y)) +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ll, ymax = ul), linetype = 'dotted', fill = 'gray') +
      geom_line(color = 'blue') +
      coord_cartesian(clip = 'on', xlim = c(1, 10), ylim = c(-5, 15)) +
      scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, 'cm'))
    
    if(!is.null(coords_round$x)){
      plot <- plot + geom_point(aes(x = coords_round$x, y = coords_round$y),
                                shape = 3, color = 'black', size = 3) +
      annotate("label", x = coords_round$x, y = coords_round$y+1.5,
               label = paste0('(', coords_round$x, ', ', coords_round$y, ')'))
    }
    plot
  })
  
  coords_round <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    coords_round$x <- signif(input$plot_click$x, 3)
    coords_round$y <- signif(input$plot_click$y, 3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I need to set the boundaries of the plot because the limits of the geom_ribbon element are so wide, but this introduces a problem because when clip is set to 'on', the annotation with the x and y coordinates also clips, so I get something that looks like this:

[image: Graph with clip on]

If, on the other hand, I set clip to 'off', geom_ribbon doesn't clip either:

[image]

Is it possible to have one element clip and another not?

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the limits for the y scale anyway, one option would be to restrict the values used for the `geom_ribbon` to the range of limits using e.g. using `pmax` you could do:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, ll = -1:-10, ul = 2:11), aes(x, y)) +
      geom_ribbon(
        aes(ymin = pmax(ll, -5), ymax = ul),
        linetype = "dotted", fill = "gray"
      ) +
      geom_line(color = "blue") +
      coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = c(1, 10), ylim = c(-5, 15)) +
      scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, "cm"))

    if (!is.null(coords_round$x)) {
      plot <- plot + geom_point(aes(x = coords_round$x, y = coords_round$y),
        shape = 3, color = "black", size = 3
      ) +
        annotate("label",
          x = coords_round$x, y = coords_round$y + 1.5,
          label = paste0("(", coords_round$x, ", ", coords_round$y, ")")
        )
    }
    plot
  })

  coords_round <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    coords_round$x <- signif(input$plot_click$x, 3)
    coords_round$y <- signif(input$plot_click$y, 3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]